# Find dimension of V

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V = R3[x]

find dimension of V and basis for V containing{ 1, (x^2)} and {1,x}

what is R3[x]?
and how can I find a dimension when V=R3[x]

Comment: What do you mean by $R_3$?

Comment: You should check that yourself. There should be a definition in the book/lecture. It could be the polynomial ring https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring where the degree is less or equal to $3$?

Answer (score 2):

Very likely $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$ denotes the vector space of polynomials of degree less than $3$ and real coefficients.

A basis of that space consists of the vectors $1,x,x^2$.

You can verify that it is a generating system since all polynomials of degree less than $3$ can be written as $a\cdot 1+b\cdot x+c\cdot x^2$. They are also linearly independent by the definition of equality between polynomials (or the identity principle if you see polynomials as the polynomial map).